# Speed issue in copying files from one host to another

Tags: linux, centos

I have at home two centos boxes:
Box A - centos 6.4. gui version
Box B - centos 7.1. minimal version.
They are connected to 100Mb router (both boxes have 100Mb network adapters). Box B has software raid 1 and sata II interfaces. Now I copy files from box A to box B. The problem is that network monitor (iptraf-ng) shows only 20000 kbps. That is around 2MB per second. I can't understand why the speed is so low and where the problem is. Help me to understand what direction should I move to solve this problem.
**EDIT 1:**
On box B samba4 is installed and I copy files to samba share. CPU load on box B is around 20% on CPU1 and 1-2% on CPU2.
**EDIT 2**
I've checked the network speed between A (server) and B(client) via iperv:

```
[root@localhost P]# iperf -c a.a.a.a
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to a.a.a.a, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 22.5 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local b.b.b.b port 53459 connected with a.a.a.a port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec   112 MBytes  94.3 Mbits/sec
```

Comment: What do you use to copy? (Also, looking at top on either end can help you figure out if it's a cpu bottleneck on either end, for example if you use `scp` with encryption and very slow hardware.)

Comment: To exclude other possibilities (slow disk, CPU), please run [`iperf`](https://iperf.fr/) or other bandwidth benchmark tool.

Comment: @Ulrich Schwarz  Thank you for your time. See edit 1.

Comment: Your problem is related to Samba.  You can tune it to improve performance, but CIFS is a crappy protocol.  If you expect near-wire speed you're going to be disappointed.

Comment: @myaut Thank you for your time. See edit 2

Comment: @lcd047 Can it be possible to decrease potencial speed (see edit 2) at 5 times?

Comment: As I said, network is _not_ your bottleneck.  You can switch to 10 Gbps and you won't make CIFS any faster.  Ask on some Samba forum about tuning tips.